# What hypothesis test can I use to test the null hypothesis that the Kurtosis of a data set is normal

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing

I am completing a stats project in R and so far I have created a function that computes the sample kurtosis of a data set. I have then used bootstrapping to compute a 95% confidence interval for the kurtosis. Now I am wanting to perform a hypothesis test where the null hypothesis is that the kurtosis is zero and the alternative hypothesis is that the kurtosis is not zero. What test should I be using for this?

I know that a zero kurtosis value suggests the data is normally distributed so should I somehow be using the student t test where I assume the data is normally distributed?

Comment: Reading over it I don't think I can use the student t-test but I also tried to apply the Wilcoxon test and I don't think that works either. I am really unsure where to even start here.

Comment: There are distributions other than normal which also have a zero excess kurtosis.  Anyway, what might $0$ lying in your confidence interval suggest?

Comment: Zero kurtosis does not suggest that the data are normally distributed: The normal distribution is but one of infinitely many distributions that have zero kurtosis. What zero kurtosis tells you is that the outlier characteristic of the distribution, as measured by kurtosis, is identical to the outlier characteristic of the normal distribution.

Comment: If zero lies inside my 95% confidence interval I cannot reject the null hypothesis and if it lies outside of my confidence interval i can reject the null hypothesis at the 5% significance level. Is this correct?